# How to get the date on a directory entry using "ls" and not on the whole directory contents?

Tags: bash, ls

I seem to want the opposite of everyone else - How may i use (in bash scripts) an `ls -al /some/path/to/where/ever/.`  to get just the entry for ".", not for everything in "."?  What I'm after is the dir's date, so. in other words, what's the date on the  `/some/path/to/where/ever/.` directory?

Doesn't have to be "ls" that is just what seemed natural.

Comment: FYI, using `ls` isn't generally the correct way to get something's date in a script. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for an explanation of why this should be avoided, and alternatives; see in particular the "getting metadata" section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do `stat` command:

```
stat -c "%y %n" .
```

OR for EPOCH value:

```
stat -c "%Y %n" .
```

Comment: `%Z` is ctime, not mtime -- that is to say, metadata update time, not file content alteration time. It's a bit unusual to want it.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the `-d` option to get the entry for the directory itself, not the contents of the directory.

```
ls -ld /some/path/to/where/ever
```

In this case, the `-a` option would be unnecessary, since you are not listing the contents of the given argument.

Comment: This is an accurate literal answer, but likely to be encouraging bad practices (parsing `ls` to extract mtime).

Comment: Good point, I didn't read the question carefully enough to see what use `ls` was being used for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ls`, you can use [stat](http://man.cx/stat) to capture the date. This way, the date isn't in a shifting format, and you don't have to filter it out from the rest of the output:

```
$ stat -f "%Sm" $directory_name
Feb 10 14:19:47 2014

$ stat -f "%Dm" $directory_name
1392059987     # Number of seconds since the "Epoch" (Usually Jan 1, 1970).
```

The `stat` command varies from system to system, so read your manpage.